# I am new to programming in C and cant find the error

Tags: c

i code in Dev cpp but i also tried the online compiler for the following code to display employees salary using conditional operators... the code does not take input for Qualification and I cant figure out why..pls Help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int yos;
    char g, q;

    printf("Enter Gender (m-Male , f-Female) : ");
    scanf("%c",&g);

    printf("Enter Years of Service : ");
    scanf("%d",&yos);

    printf("Enter Qualification (g-Graduate , p-Post Graduate) : ");
    scanf("%c",&q);

    printf("Your Salary is : ");
    
        if(g=='f'&&yos>=10&&q=='p')
    printf("12000");
    
        if(g=='m'&&yos>=10&&q=='p')
    printf("11000");
    
        if(g=='m'&&yos>=10&&q=='g'||g=='m'&&yos<10&&q=='p'||g=='f'&&yos<10&&q=='p')
    printf("10000");
    
        if(g=='f'&&yos>=10&&q=='g')
    printf("9000");
    
        if(g=='m'&&yos<10&&q=='g')
    printf("7000");
    
        if(g=='f'&&yos<10&&q=='g')
    printf("6000");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about their differences.

Comment: Or writing interrop code.

Comment: You would make your code way more readable by applying some common indentation and adding some spaces to your conditions.

Comment: Unrelated: Always check the result codes returned by functions. Programmers tend to be an interesting mix of lazy and speed-obsessed they wouldn't waste their time or the computers with code to provide diagnostics if the diagnostics weren't important.

Comment: When you get unexpected results and can't figure out why, start printing out the variables involved so you have a better idea of why a particular bad decision was made by the program.

Comment: Here is another duplicate question, which has received many more upvotes: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789/12149471)

Comment: add leading space in your scanf, example: scanf("  %d",&yos) or scanf("  %c",&g);